# Динамическая форма на ajax php запрос

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать динамическую форму.  Есть форма добавления объявлений. В форме есть выбор категории. Как сделать, чтобы в зависимости от выбранной категории подгружались характеристики? Например машина - макс скорость, одежда - размер.

Answer (score 2):

На `<input>` категории повесить обработчик события *onchange*. В этом обработчике сделать одно из трех:

- либо (если поля, входящие в вариативную часть, не включены в форму) загрузить вариативную часть формы ajax'ом и добавить ее в форму, а не требующиеся для данной категории - удалить,
- либо (если в форму включены уже все необходимые поля, и те, которые зависят от выбора категории, сделаны изначально скрытыми) скрыть все поля, не относящиеся к выбранной категории, и сделать видимыми те поля, которые должны заполняться для этой категории,
- либо (если в форму включены уже все необходимые поля, и те, которые зависят от выбора категории, сделаны изначально запрещенными для редактирования) запретить для редактирования все поля, не относящиеся к выбранной категории, и разрешить для редактирования те поля, которые должны заполняться для этой категории.

Для скрытых (запрещенных для редактирования) полей не забудьте по *onchange* сбросить значения, чтобы они не отправлялись по *submit*. Это все - javascript.

Comment: Ну примерно понял спасибо